# Add a second account with the same email address in Outlook

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook-365

I'm trying to add a second account with the same email address in Outlook 365 (the version that opens via `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE` which I believe is not the "app version"). It doesn't matter if I check the check box under advanced settings:

[image]

Unfortunately it only show me the error message (within the wizard window), that the email address has been added already (translation from German):

[image]

Is there a workaround? Renaming the email address doesn't work, since Outlook won't accept an invalid email.

PS. feel free to replace my German screenshot with Englisch ones.

Comment: Go to Control Panel, Mail and try adding the account there. This is the best way to add accounts. However Outlook may still complain because it will not know how to deal with two accounts that are the same.

Comment: Why would you want to add two accounts with the same address?

Comment: @John Control panel gives you the same dialogue with the add account button, but it opens the a different wizard. Ok, but it says in control panel "Mail (Microsoft Outlook 2016)",strange, thx!

Comment: @MátéJuhász because I want to ;) (no, joke aside, it's a very narrow use case and not relevant to the question, there is no way around it)

Comment: @John feel free to write an answer, or I can just add one myself.

Comment: I have done that for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal Outlook Wizard is sometimes limiting.

You can add an Account using Control Panel, Mail. This is usually the best way (for me, in any event).

Open Email Accounts and select New.

Here is a Screen Shot to illustrate.

[image]

Comment: Does not work with two *Exchange* accounts, Outlook will still prevent you from setting up a secondary account with the same e-mail address, which would be useful in a migration scenario.

Comment: You cannot use 2 Exchange Accounts in one profile